# Ruby on Rails: How can I query or filter a computed method from the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to RoR and I'm not sure if I am asking the right question. However here it is.

I have 3 models Policy, CommissionInvoice, Intermediary

Intermediary -

```
    has_many :commission_invoices, foreign_key: :intm_no
```

CommissionInvoice -

```
    belongs_to :policy, foreign_key: :policy_id
    has_one :intermediary, foreign_key: :intm_no
```

Policy -

```
    has_one :commission_invoice, foreign_key: :policy_id
    has_one :intermediary, through: :commission_invoice, foreign_key: :intm_no
```

In my Intermediary model I made a method like this:

```
  def credit_term
    if type == "BR"
      90
    else
      30
    end
  end
```

Then in my Policy model I made a method like this:

```
  def due_date
    effectivity + intermediary.credit_term if commission_invoice
  end
```

**effectivity** is a column name.

And for my PoliciesController:

```
  def due_today
    @policies = Policy.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).includes([:commission_invoice => :intermediary]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
```

Now, my question is, how can I filter the queried data from the controller(or if you can suggest any other solution) using the computed method  **due_date** to the Date today? Because all of the records from the very start are being displayed. I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using the Array select method: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select

For example:

```
def due_today
    @policies = Policy.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).includes([:commission_invoice => :intermediary]).page(params[:page]).per(10)

    @policies = @policies.select {|p| p.due_date.present? && p.due_date <= Date.today}
end
```

I added a check for `due_date.present?` because if `commission_invoice` is falsey, `due_date` will return `nil`.

Comment: where will i put it, in the controller? or in the view?

Comment: Technically you can put it in either the controller or the view, but I think it's cleaner to put it in the controller. I edited my answer to show it.

Comment: I've been checking my filtered data and i think its fine now, however it only hides the policies that do not fall on the due_date from the view module and the record still shows it queried all the policies because through scanning on the other pages, they are blank though it says that it has 1 of -- policies. How can I make the view module to only query all the policies that are due today and will not take up other policies? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `@policies.select...` line is filtering the array in memory, but the database query (the line above) is returning all the policies (the 10 policies on that page.. looks like you're using a gem for pagination).If you want your database query to only return the filtered policies, it might get tricky, because what is `credit_term`, a number of days? It's a lot easier to add days to a date in ruby than in sql. It might be easiest if you add a due_date column to the policies table and filter by that.